# PHP foreach with API calls on id

Tags: php, curl, guzzle, craftcms

I am trying to add data from 2 APIs to my database (using CraftCMS). I am querying 2 endpoints - one of which queries all posts (/postings) then another queries each post (/postings/). I am currently looping through each item in the postings API then querying the API:

```
foreach ($data AS $item) {
  $this->queryPostingItem($item->id);
}
```

I am using Guzzle to fetch the data in each method. But getting a curl timeout error. What options do I have to fetch all the posting data? I believe that there is a limit of 2 api calls per second. I have tried adding `sleep(1);` to the loop after every few loops but it isn't helping.

Bit stuck.

Comment: ```foreach ($data AS $item) {
  while(!$this->queryPostingItem($item->id)){
        /*probably hitting api rate limit, sleep a bit and try again*/sleep(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @hanshenrik
I have tried - ```$newData = array_chunk($data, 2);
        foreach ($newData AS $data) {
            sleep(4);
            foreach ($data AS $key => $item) { $this->queryPostingItem($item->id); }
```

But still get a timeout error

Comment: what timeout error? show us the CURLOPT_VERBOSE response, are you talking about a server-generated timeout error (which would imply api ratelimiting), or are you talking about a libcurl-generated timeout? (which would imply that you need to increase CURLOPT_TIMEOUT / CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT), or are you talking about a php-timeout? (which means you'll need to increase php's set_time_limit()) or are you talking about your own web server's limit, eg nginx/apache php gateway timeout?

Comment: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 2047 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Comment: "*I believe that there is a limit of 2 api calls per second*" - sounds like there are rate limits on this API, and they are documented? Sometimes there are per-second rate limits as well as total request limits, are you now hitting the latter?  Maybe a question for their support.

Comment: @PeterAyelloWright try setting CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT to 5 and run it again, what do you get?

Comment: you can use concurrency it will send exactly 2 at a time then put a sleep in every concurrent loop of guzzle, would solve the issue

Comment: Ok I did more digging and found - $response = $client->send($request, ['timeout' => 10,'headers' => [ $headers ]]); and set the timeout to 10 seconds. Was previously not set. This seems to load now or at least doesn't error out.